# PHP: Database Connection Class - Won't Connect

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm having trouble with my `DatabaseConnection` class. I cannot seem to get `$dbUser` or `$dbName` variables to work for this connection class. I currently have to manually put the values in with quotes. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
class DatabaseConnection {
    private $dbHost = "localhost";
    private $dbUser = "root";
    private $dbPass = "";
    private $dbName = "test";

    function __construct() {
        $connection = mysql_connect($dbHost, "root", $dbPass)
            or die("Could not connect to the database:<br />" . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("test", $connection) 
            or die("Database error:<br />" . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

If you have suggestions for improving my current class, by all means, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a class, you have to access your class variables using `$this->dbHost`, `$this->dbUser`, etc instead of `$dbHost`, `$dbUser`. Php requires that you use $this->variableName for class variables.

EDIT:

Here's your code with the mysql_connect variables changed to access your class variables

```
class DatabaseConnection {
    private $dbHost = "localhost";
    private $dbUser = "root";
    private $dbPass = "";
    private $dbName = "test";

    function __construct() {
        $connection = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass)
            or die("Could not connect to the database:<br />" . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("test", $connection) 
            or die("Database error:<br />" . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that makes sense, thank you. Another quick question, but is it right that I set those variables to `private`, or should they simply be `var`?

Comment: Yes, private is the way to go. You want to make it so your class controls access to those variables.